# List to list of tuples conversion

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am brand new to Python.  I can change a list to a tuple, for example

```
li = [1]
tuple(li)
```

I am trying to create a tuple that gives the item and its position, so a tuple that would come out `(1, 0)`. I have no idea how to get started.

Comment: `enumerate(li)` gives you what you want with the tuples flipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a just one tuple you could do this:

```
li = (list[1], 1)
```

The brackets here are the literal syntax for tuples.

If you wanted to do it for all the elements of the list, you could use a list comprehension:

```
lis = [(list[i], i) for i in range(len(list))]
```

Which would create a list of tuples were each tuple has the element and its index.

Comment: this works well.  What if I want to do a traditional for loop like I would do in R?  I flip flopped the code  and put   for I in range(len(list)):   lis = [(list[I], I)] and it gives me the last tuple in a list.  I know I need some sort of code to add each tuple to the list, but I keep either getting the first or the last tuple that would be present.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea. Each iteration of the loop would give you a different tuple. If you try to use lis outside of the loop it would equal the last tuple from your input list because that was the value it had at the last iteration of your loop. And if you wanted to add each tuple to a list you can just append() them each iteration.

Comment: so I tried something like this:          for m in range(len(li)):
        lis = [(list[m], m)]
        lis.append(m)    but keep getting an error.  Am I using append correctly?

Comment: Create a separate array outside of the loop and then append your tuples to that instead. And lis is your tuple, m is just a number. So you'd want to make it array.append(lis) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a **tuple of tuples**, you can use a generator expression like this;

```
li = [4, 5, 6]
tuple((li[i], i) for i in range(len(li)))
```

Or with enumerate;

```
tuple((v, k) for k,v in enumerate(li))
```

Both will return;

```
((4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2))
```

If you want a **list of tuples**, you can use a list comprehension expression like this;

```
[(li[i], i) for i in range(len(li))]
```

or with enumerate;

```
[(v,k) for k, v in enumerate(li)]
```

Both will return;

```
[(4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2)]
```

Comment: It's generally considered a bad practice. Consider using `enumerate`.

Comment: I also added an option with enumerate using a generator expression. And also added list comprehension versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) which does exactly what you need, just with elements and indexes flipped:

```
> li = [2, 4, 6]
> [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(li)]
[(2, 0), (4, 1), (6, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate),

```
li = [10, 20, 30]
list(enumerate(li))
```

prints

```
[(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30)]
```

If you want the output to be in (item, position) order, you can use,

```
[(v, k) for k,v in enumerate(li)]
```

Comment: The OP want a tuple, not a list

Comment: can you explain a little more? What'd be the expected output for [10, 20, 30] input list?

Comment: the expected output would be [(10, 0), (20, 1), (30, 2)].  It looks like enumerate and zip work, but I am trying to do it with a traditional loop as I am just beginning the language and need to learn the beginning code techniques before getting into the more advanced, simplifying techniques

Answer (score 0):

`zip` with `range` is another option:

```
In [4]: li = [2,4,6]

In [5]: zip(li, range(len(li)))
Out[5]: [(2, 0), (4, 1), (6, 2)]
```